# Find leaf folders that aren't hidden folders

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a folder structure with some epubs and json files in the down-most folders (not counting the `.ts` folders). I'm exporting tags from the json files to tagspaces, by creating a `.ts` folder with some other `json` files. I've already processed part of the files and now I want to find the leaf folders that don't have a `.ts` folder in their path, to find the remaining files without having to process the others twice.

So for this example I only want to do something for the folder `t5`:

```
test
├── t1
│   ├── t2
│   │   └── t5
│   └── t3
│       └── .ts
└── .ts
    └── t4
```

This is what I've tried:

```
def process_files_in_leaf_subdirectories(dir: str) -> None:
    dirs = []
    for root, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(dir):
        if subdirs or '.ts' in root:
            continue
        dirs.append(root)
    return dirs


def test_process_files_in_leaf_subdirectories():
    os.makedirs('tmp/t1/t2/t5', exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs('tmp/t1/t3/.ts', exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs('tmp/.ts/t4', exist_ok=True)
    assert get_files_in_leaf_subdirectories('tmp') == ['tmp/t1/t2/t5']
    shutil.rmtree('tmp')
```

[context](https://git.disroot.org/hirrolot19/AO3Scraper/src/commit/44bf8f40a8b83258a52d86065947a7e57be29cfa/export_tags.py)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So all we need to do is find leaf dir without the `.ts` subdir? Looks like `pathlib.Path` would be a better starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to find leaf directory, without counting `.ts` directory - just recursively visiting non-hidden path and *yielding* directories without any subdirectory would be enough.

For such path operations in python, I'd recommend using [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#module-pathlib) instead.

Here's generator to yield leaf directories without any subdir:

```py
import pathlib

def find_leaf_dir_gen(root_path: pathlib.Path) -> pathlib.Path:

    # filter subdirectories
    child_dirs = [path for path in root_path.iterdir() if path.is_dir()]

    # if no child_dir, yield & return
    if not child_dirs:
        yield root_path
        return
    
    # otherwise iter tru subdir
    for path in child_dirs:
        # ignore hidden dir
        if path.stem[0] == ".":
            continue

        # step in and recursive yield
        yield from find_leaf_dir_gen(path)
```

Sample usage

```py
>>> leaves = list(find_leaf_dir_gen(ROOT))
>>> leaves
[WindowsPath('X:/test/t1/t2/t5'), WindowsPath('X:/test/t1/t3/t6')]

>>> for path in leaves:
...     ts_path = path.joinpath(".ts")
...     ts_path.mkdir()
```

Test directory structure - Before:

```
X:\TEST
├─.ts
│  └─t4
└─t1
    ├─t2
    │  └─t5
    └─t3
        ├─.ts
        └─t6
```

After:

```
X:\TEST
├─.ts
│  └─t4
└─t1
    ├─t2
    │  └─t5
    │      └─.ts
    └─t3
        ├─.ts
        └─t6
            └─.ts
```